# Какой синтаксис postgresql 8.3.7 на создание таблиц

Tags: postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста перевести синтаксис под postgresql 8.3.7

Создание таблицы
$query = "create table if not exists orderst".$akklogin." (id int(2) primary key auto_increment, zakaz MEDIUMTEXT NULL, zakaz2 MEDIUMTEXT NULL, data MEDIUMTEXT NULL, time MEDIUMTEXT NULL, idzakaz MEDIUMTEXT NULL);";

и чистый sql

create table if not exists orderst1234 (id int(2) primary key auto_increment, zakaz MEDIUMTEXT NULL, zakaz2 MEDIUMTEXT NULL, data MEDIUMTEXT NULL, time MEDIUMTEXT NULL, idzakaz MEDIUMTEXT NULL);

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE orderst (id serial PRIMARY KEY,zakaz text, zakaz2 text, data text, time text, idzakaz text)